# File version.h not found building Logitech C270 driver

Tags: linux, makefile

I am installing some drivers on Linux to use a webcam *(Logitech C270 / drivers: http://qce-ga.sourceforge.net/)*.

I am following the tutorial on the website. I downloaded the .tar.gz file and extracted with `tar zxvf qc-usb-X.XX.tar.gz`. But when I go to the folder created and do the command `make all`, I got this error:

```
awk: /lib/modules/4.4.74/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
sh: 132608: unknown operand
sh: 132608: unknown operand
cc -I/lib/modules/4.4.74/build/include -nostdinc -iwithprefix include -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__ -DNOKERNEL -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -wall -Wstrict-prototype s -Wno-trographs -DHAVE_UTSRELEASE_H= -pipe -c qc-driver.c
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:175: qc-driver.0] Error 127
```

For Hardware, I am using Onion Omega2+ (https://onion.io/omega2/) which is running with Linux LEDE.

If someone knows why I have this error, I would be so grateful! Thanks!

Comment: You have to install your linux headers https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files

Comment: @hellow Thank you for your response, I had few issues with it because of Linux LEDE, but if is it really needed, I will check this! Thanks!

Comment: You also need to install a C compiler, to solve this error: `cc: Command not found`